# Access a static array defined in another cxx file

Tags: c++, arrays, static, extern

I have a program that links to a shared library. This library includes a RandomFile.cxx file, which has an array definition like this:

```cpp
static double randomArray[] = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3};
```

In the header file RandomFile.hxx of RandomFile.cxx, there is no extern, getter, or anything regarding the randomArray.

In my program, I want to somehow access this array.

So far I have tried:

```cpp
// sizeOfRandomArray was calculated by counting the elements.
int sizeOfRandomArray = 3;

// 1st attempt: does not compile because of undefined reference to the array
extern double randomArray[sizeOfRandomArray];

// 2nd attempt: does not compile because of undefined reference to the array
extern "C" double randomArray[sizeOfRandomArray];

// 3rd attempt: does not compile because of undefined reference to the array
extern "C++" double randomArray[sizeOfRandomArray];

// 4th attempt: compiles but i don't get the actual values
extern "C" {
double randomArray[sizeOfRandomArray];  
}

// 5th attempt: compiles but i don't get the actual values
extern "C++" {
double randomArray[sizeOfRandomArray];
}

// 6th attempt: compiles and works but I overload my code with the whole RandomFile.cxx file.
#include "RandomFile.cxx"
```

I can't(don't want to) change the RandomFile.cxx because it is part of a big library named [VTK](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk).

Is there any possible way to do it, without including the cxx file or copying the array in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Including the cxx to your code would be a bad idea, don't do it...

Comment: The shared library must have functions. Do any of them access and return this array?

Comment: Some access it (in cxx) but none returns it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable defined with with `static` [linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Linkage) in one [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) is (in a way) "private" to that translation unit.

No other translation units can access that variable.

So no it't not possible to access that array directly.

As a work-around you might consider creating a class, and put the array inside the class. Then you could use member-functions to access the class in an indirect way. If you only want one instance of the array (and not one per object instance of the class) then you can make it `static` in the class.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can access that object without modifications to the RandomFile.cxx.
Just remove the `static` specifier in the RandomFile.cxx file and declare the object as `extern` in the common header RandomFile.hxx or the target translation unit that needs access. This makes the object have a static duration with external linkage:

RandomFile.hxx:

```
 constexpr int sizeOfRandomArray=3
 extern double randomArray[sizeOfRandomArray];
```

RandomFile.cxx:

```
 double randomArray[sizeOfRandomArray] {1,2,3};
```

See:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

Remember that if you miss the size in declaration, no other translation unit than RandomFile.cxx will be aware of the array size.

Cheers,
FM.

Comment: I don't want to do that because it's a big library that I am not the author of it.